# how to escape characters in xdotool

Tags: xdotool

I have this script to open a new console, ssh into a server, run a deploy command.

I pass to the script the version of the deploy

```
xdotool key ctrl+alt+t
sleep 3
xdotool type "ssh myserver"
xdotool key Return
sleep 10
xdotool type "password"
xdotool key Return
xdotool type "sh path-to-script/deploy.sh $1"
xdotool key Return
```

I have several problems with this and I allready tried to google for a solution without success.

- the character `/` its transformed to an `&`. when I run the script
- copy&pasting in the console it works, but no if I run it as a sh file
- the $1 is not evaluated

Can you give me any pointer in making this work. xdotool is not mandatory, I would use whatever it works

**note:** I can't by pass the ssh with a command becouse the security politics of the company and also don't know how to do it if I can't the settings in *myserver*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Similar problem here:
http://code.google.com/p/semicomplete/issues/detail?id=13#c29 
Try:

```
xdotool type setxkbmap de
xdotool key Return
xdotool type "sh path-to-script/deploy.sh $1"
xdotool key Return
```

---

Maybe it works better if you write a script:

```
#!/bin/bash
xterm -e "ssh myserver \"sh path-to-script/deploy.sh $1\"; sleep 5"
```

and invoke it like this:

```
./theAboveScript.sh &
sleep 10
xdotool type "password"
xdotool key Return
```

Comment: the second option is good, the problem is it jumps with exec request failed on channel 0. I tried with ssh myserver "ls" and same result, in other server it works, I think it may be server ssh configuration. Something I can't modify

Answer (score 0):

"expect" could be a good solution.

You can start following as a script with your parameter.

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
spawn ssh myserver;
expect "Password:";
send "password\n";
expect "me@myserver:~$";
send "sh path-to-script/deploy.sh $argv\n";
interact
```